# Inverse of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have given

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{a} + 1\right)^{-\frac{1}{a}}$$

And am trying to invert it, but despairing.

Perhaps it helps (but I wouldn't know) that $f$ comes from

$$
g(m,n) = mn (m^a + n^a)^{-1/a}\\
f(x) = g(1/x, 1)\\
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \bigg( \bigg( \frac{1}{x} \bigg)^a +1 \bigg)^{-\frac{1}{a}}$

$= \bigg( \bigg( \frac{1}{x} \bigg)^a \bigg)^{\frac{1}{a}} \bigg( \bigg( \frac{1}{x} \bigg)^a +1 \bigg)^{-\frac{1}{a}} $

$ = \bigg( \frac{ \big( \frac{1}{x} \big)^a}{\big( \frac{1}{x} \big)^a+1} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{a}}$

$=\bigg( 1- \frac{ 1}{\big( \frac{1}{x} \big)^a+1} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{a}}$

Now you only have one $x$ in the formula. Proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $f(x) = y$ and raising both sides to the power of $-a$ we have $$\begin{align}y^{-a}=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-a}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{a} + 1\right) \\ = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-a}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{a} + \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-a}\\ = 1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-a} \\ = 1+x^a \\ \implies x^a = y^{-a}-1 \\ \implies x(y) = \left(\frac{1}{y^a}-1 \right)^{1/a}\end{align}$$